Cleveref capitalizes too much
Consider the following document:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
    \begin{theorem}
        \label{thm}
        Theorem
    \end{theorem}
    \begin{proof}[Proof of the \namecref{thm}]
        Proof.
    \end{proof}
    See \cref{thm} on \cpageref{thm}.
\end{document}

Here, all references are capitalized: while the capitalization in \cref{thm} is intended, I find the capitalization of \cpageref and \namecref odd. Is there a way to just capitalize \cref (without resorting to \Cref)?

You're asking to capitalize, so what did you expect?

redefine \cref as \Cref?

@egreg It's not uncommon in English publications to capitalize numbered chapters, theorems etc., but definitely uncommon to capitalize pages.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz redefining has other implications; e.g., \Cref does not put abbreviations.

@Bubaya As far as I can see, the capitalization happens at definition time; \cref and \namecref use the same mechanism. The only possibility I see is to do a bunch of \crefname declarations, in order to get \namecref not to be capitalized.

For the capitalization of pages, you can use \Crefname{page}{page}{pages}. For \namecref it is what egreg says: trickier...

If you want nameref to be lower case, use \lcnamecref{thm}

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I didn't know that one! :-)

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Okay, I think this (and busbrs's comment) solve my problem.
